# Top notation as exponent

Tags: notation

In cryptography, what does the Top notation mean? It resembles a capital T: T

In particular, I saw it in the follwing context:

$c = (c_1,c_2)^\top$

where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are homomorphic ciphertexts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, $^\top$ denotes the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of a matrix or vector.
Common variants include $^t$ and $^T$.

---

Hence $(c_1,c_2)^\top$ is just $\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix}$. Such notation is often used to fit column vectors neatly into text.